# Calling a class function inside another class function

Tags: python, class

I am trying to call a function inside another class function in Python. However, I am getting the error that global `name` is not defined. I don't know what to do as I can't figure out what's the issue.
The error is:

```
NameError: global name 'sendCmdWaitForRaffleResponse' is not defined
```

Here is the code I have written:

```
Class T:
    def connect(self,ipAddr,portNum):
      try:
           print "Check1"
           s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

           s.connect((ipAddr,portNum))
           s.settimeout(1000*30)

           response=s.recv(8192)
           print response



           cmd="some command"
           s.send(cmd)
           print 'check'
           response=s.recv(1024)

           print response
           #time.sleep(5)
      except Exception as e:
           print e
  def Send(self,command):
         result ="ok"
         try:
             print "start"
             if command.startswith("#"):
               #print result
               return result

             elif not command:
                 return result

             print 'yes'
             result=sendCmdWaitResponse(command)

         except Exception as e:
             print (e)

         return result

  def sendCmdWaitResponse(self,cmd):
          print "Running"
          s.send(cmd)
          while true:
              response=s.recv(1024)
              response=+ '\n'
              print response

          print "Leaving"
          return sb.getvalue()

if __name__ == "__main__":

 test=T()
 a='some command'
 test.Connect(ipaddr,port)
 test.Send(a)
```

Comment: @SuperStew please consider editing the post instead of pointing out trivial grammar flaws :)

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry.My bad.I apologize for it

Comment: Please fix the indentaiton of the code (you may want to include the `class` line, to help make everything line up properly, even if you skip other stuff in the class). Also, since you're getting an exception, please include the full traceback, as a separate code block (it may be wider than the Stack Overflow page, but that's fine, let it generate scroll bars). The traceback will tell us exactly where your error is occurring, so we don't need to guess. I *suspect* that your issue has to do with the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block being indented inside the class, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: No the main function is not indented inside the class

Comment: `name 'sendCmdWaitResponse' is not defined`

Comment: Its defined.The function with that name is defined

Answer (score 0):

You need self.

```
         result=self.sendCmdWaitResponse(command)
```

Comment: I did that.Now I'm getting error global name s not defined in s.send(cmd)

Comment: I've added that function.send and recv are sockets functions

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
result=sendCmdWaitResponse(command)
```

to

```
result=self.sendCmdWaitResponse(command)
```

Comment: I did that.Now I'm getting error global name s not defined in s.send(cmd)

Comment: @Rock yes, that is expected because `s.send` does not exist. `s.recv` and `sb.getvalue` do not exist too. Please add missing code and post valid code.

Comment: I've added that function.send and recv are sockets functions

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have many typo: This is the fix I have done. I don't know what is your expected output. Please add the valid code:

```
import socket
class T():

    def __init__(self, ipAddr, portNum):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def connect(self,ipAddr,portNum):
      try:
           print "Check1"
           s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

           s.connect((ipAddr,portNum))
           s.settimeout(1000*30)

           response=s.recv(8192)
           print response

           cmd="some command"
           s.send(cmd)
           print 'check'
           response=s.recv(1024)

           print response
       #time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
      print e

   def Send(self, command):
     result ="ok"
     try:
         print "start"
         if command.startswith("#"):
           #print result
           return result

         elif not command:
             return result

         print 'yes'
         result= self.sendCmdWaitResponse(command)

     except Exception as e:
         print (e)

     return result


    def sendCmdWaitResponse(self,cmd):
      print "Running"
      self.s.send(cmd)
      while True:
          response= self.s.recv(1024)
          response=+ '\n'
          print response

      print "Leaving"
      return sb.getvalue()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    a='some command'
    ipAddr = ""

    port = 1000
    test = T(ipAddr, port)
    test.connect(ipAddr,port)
    test.Send(a)
```

Comment: Sorry.I have created the socket in the connect function and want to use the socket.send and socket.recv commands in another function. And one more thing ggmu

Comment: @Rock So, you want to use `socket.send` and `socket.recv` in `sendCmdWaitResponse(self,cmd)` ? GGMU :)

Comment: If you want to use `s` variable from `connect` function,  use `constructor` and initialize it while instantiating the class.

Comment: Yes I want to use the socket.send and socket.recv function.GGMU

Comment: I defined the sockets in my main function therefore making it global.Now I can use it in the other class functions.Thanks for the help